# Informação padrão de um registro

Tags: sql, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela `[produto]` e uma tabela `[produto_embalagem]`, que podem conter várias embalagens de um único produto.

A discussão é se a embalagem padrão do produto deve ser uma marcação na tabela `[produto_embalagem]` ou um campo `[id_produto_embalagem]` na tabela `[produto]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tecnicamente funciona com qualquer uma das formas. Você deve verificar qual das duas formas proporciona o melhor `index` no banco. Isso vai depender das queries que são lançadas no banco de dados, então você precisa analisar as aplicações que se conectam nessa base de dados e ver quais queries elas costumam lançar.

Por exemplo, se a aplicação geralmente precisa obter o produto de uma determinada embalagem padrão, a seguinte query vai se repetir bastante:

```
select * from produto where id_embalagem_padrao = 123
```

Então, neste caso, faz sentido você ter a FK na tabela `produto` e criar um índice para ela.

No entanto, se é mais comum a aplicação buscar a embalagem padrão de um determinado produto, será a seguinte query que vai se repetir bastante:

```
select * from produto_embalagem where id_produto_padrao = 123
```

Daí neste segundo cenário você vai preferir ter a FK na tabela `produto_embalagem` e ter um índice pra ela.

Você deve analisar a sua aplicação e ver qual das duas situações é mais comum.

Comment: Mas qual seria a maneira mais "acadêmica"? Existe algum tipo de melhores práticas para esta situação?

Comment: @RicardoMelo Adicionei dois exemplos pra tornar mais claro.

Comment: Muito obrigado!